Emojis to string representation in BigQuery
I have a list of strings in a bigquery table, some of which contain emoji's. I want to convert the emoji to a text representation of what it is. what is the best way to do this?
For example:
'On Holiday! '
Should be become:
'On Holiday! brazil'
I want to avoid creating a really long case statement.

What have you considered already?  Have you looked for data that maps a Unicode character to a description?  Have you seen if emoji unicode characters are within certain ordinal bounds?
